# Jmeter2.11 version script having .jsp files

Tags: javascript

I tried to record a web application using jmeter2.11. script recorded successfully.

I found some JSP files in the script and it has dynamic value like timestamp.

I am not able to cooreleate and while replaying its showing bad request and failing.

How to resolve this issue?